# Schema microdata: Is it damaging to reference an item that is only present on some pages?

Tags: seo, schema.org, microdata

I'm building a WordPress theme. The LocalBusiness entity is stated in the header of the website (present on every page). I would like to "itemref" the business **description**, which is only present on the home page. I can put the reference in and it will work on the home page, but on every other page there will be a reference to a non-existent item. Is this a bad thing or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `itemref` attribute can only be used for referencing elements from the *same* document.

What to do instead?

- You could duplicate the `description` on each page. If you don’t want to have it as visible content, you could use a `meta` element.
- You could omit the `description` on the additional pages.
- You could (and should anyway) provide the `url` for the item (typically the homepage, if the whole site is about this business), and hope that consumers interested in this item will follow the URL to learn more about it (so they would find the `description`).

Comment: Hi unor, thanks for your response. The description is a visible item on the home page only. I suppose that I could add a meta element with the same ID on every other page, as the ID itself won't appear more than once per page...

Comment: @MikeChivington: I’m not sure I understand … why would you need an ID? If you decide to include the description on all pages (personally, I wouldn’t do it), you can simply use `<meta itemprop="description" content="…" />`.

Comment: Okay, so I have the entire `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness/"` inside of header.php. That `itemscope` uses `itemref` twice to refer to one `<div>` within the page content, and another within the footer (neither are inside the `itemscope`). The `itemscope` is present on every page, as is the referenced footer `<div>`, but the content `<div>` only appears on the home page.

Comment: @MikeChivington: Yeah, that’s how I understood it. You could simply add the `meta` element in the header.php for the non-homepage pags, in scope of the `LocalBusiness` item. No need for `itemref` (but wouldn’t harm either, if that works better with your setup).

Comment: You're probably right. The `<meta>` element would just make things easier all round. Saves having to worry about conditional items and changing every page. Tbh I never used `<meta>` elements in that way before, so it didn't even spring to mind! Thanks.